# How to reset a VM to a previous snapshot?

Tags: virtualbox

I am running Ubuntu virtual machine on Ubuntu host machine using VirtualBox.
I installed some softwares on my virtual machine. I wonder if there is a method to reset my current virtual machine to a given previous state (snapshot) of my choice? How can I do that? How can I  reset to a previous snapshot undoing any changes I will make further to my VM?

Any method is welcome, especially the ones I can program either in a bash script or any programming language.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

#### Take a snapshot

From the Virtual Box GUI (Virtualbox Manager) when *Machine > Tools > Snapshots* is selected we can easily take a snapshot from a running virtual machine by selecting *Take Snapshot* or pressing <kbd>HOST</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>:

[image]

This will open a dialog to give in a sensible name and optionally a description of this snapshot:

[image]

The snapshot will then be saved in the machine's directory (depending on the size of the machine this may take a while).

On the command line the same can be achieved by

```
VBoxManage snapshot <Name_of_VM> take <Name_of_Snapshot>
```

#### Restore a snapshot

From the Virtualbox Manager we can restore a **shut down** virtual machine to any snapshot by selecting a machine's *Snapshots (1)*:

[image]

Select the appropriate snapshot from the list, then press [image] to restore this snapshot.

**The current state of the machine will then be lost.** To also restore the current state we will first have to create a snapshot too.

Restoring a snapshot from the command line is done with

```
VBoxManage snapshot <Name_of_VM> restore <Name_of_Snapshot>
```

Comment: Note: the restore snapshot button will only be enabled when the VM is powered down.

Comment: Saved my day :)

Comment: Also useful. Viewing available snapshots while on the command line can be done with `vboxmanage snapshot VM_NAME list`

Comment: In version 6, the button to access snapshots and logs is inside the VM's button on the list in the left panel.