# How to create a system restore point in Ubuntu (32bit) (running in VirtualBox)?

Tags: virtualbox, restore

I am running Ubuntu (32 bit) in VirtualBox. 
I tried to install TimeShift (a tool for system restore), using commands in Terminal, as shown [in this website](http://linuxg.net/how-to-install-timeshift-1-0-4-on-ubuntu-13-10-13-04-12-10-12-04-linux-mint-16-15-14-13-elementary-os-0-2-and-pear-os-8/)

When I tried to run the ccommands mentioned in the website, I get errors.

The commands are:

```
sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:teejee2008/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install timeshift
```

How to create a system restore point in Ubuntu (32bit)?

Comment: Ubuntu 13.04. is no longer supported and will lead to errors from installing software the way some out-dated tutorials told you.

Answer (score 3):

The **fastest** and most secure "create a system restore point" procedure I can think of when running Virtual Box is simply creating a snapshot.

[image]

See [How to reset a VM to a previous snapshot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/499103/how-to-reset-a-vm-to-a-previous-snapshot)